# Does BehaviorSubject's next clone an object, or return a reference?

Tags: typescript, object, rxjs, behaviorsubject

I'm wondering if `BehaviorSubject`'s `next` function **clones an object** or **returns a reference**.

e.g.

```js
private _currentVegBehaviorSubj = new BehaviorSubject<any>(undefined);
let carrot = { color: "Orange" };
_currentVegBehaviorSubj.next(carrot);
```

Has this carrot object been cloned?

Comment: I doesn't touch values that go through at all so it always passes just references.

Comment: you could easily ensure that by adding `_currentVegBehaviorSubj.subscribe(value => { console.log(carrot === value); })`